Date Picker, dynamically enable / disable dates
I'm trying to work out how to dynamically enable and disable dates using MultiDatesPicker for jQuery UI. http://luca.lauretta.info/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/
I can use addDisabledDates and pass an array of dates to the picker, these dates will then show as disabled. That works, but how do I enable them again ?
I've tried amending the array of dates, and recalling the date picker, but that doesn't seem to load the new dates.. the old dates are still showing as disabled.
This is a sample of what I'm doing:
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    addeddates = ['1 January 1970', '5 November 2024', '6 November 2024']       
    datepicker()
    
    function datepicker() {
            
        $('.cals').multiDatesPicker({
        dateFormat: "d MM yy",
        minDate: 0, // today
        maxDate: 365, // +30 days from today
        multidate: true,
        defaultDate:"0d", 
        addDisabledDates: addeddates,
        beforeShow: function(d) {
            addeddates = ['1 January 1970']     
            datepicker()
            }
        })
    }

})

When the date picker is called 5th and 6th November are disabled. I was hoping updating the addeddates array to be only one day and then recalling the function would allow them to be usable.
Is there anyway to dynamically enable / disable the dates ?
I'm open to using another date picker if it supports multiple dates and can be using on multiple input fields on the same page.
Thanks

Looks like you have to rebuild them each time.
https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/om7hu4ga/60/
JavaScript
function buildDatePicker(target) {
  $(target).multiDatesPicker("destroy")
  $(target).multiDatesPicker({
    addDisabledDates: $("#mdp-demo-a").multiDatesPicker("getDates"),
  })
}

$("#mdp-demo-a").multiDatesPicker({
  onSelect: function (dt, ui) {
    console.log("A - Date Selected.")
    if ($("#mdp-demo-b, #mdp-demo-c").prop("disabled")) {
      $("#mdp-demo-b, #mdp-demo-c")
        .prop("disabled", false)
        .multiDatesPicker({
          addDisabledDates: $("#mdp-demo-a").multiDatesPicker("getDates"),
        })
    }
    buildDatePicker("#mdp-demo-b, #mdp-demo-c")
  },
})

I disabled the secondary ones until the first had a value. Not doing this might throw errors about them not being initialized as MultiDatePckers or DatePicker.

Thanks this is really helpful. If I add a date to A, then that date is not available in B or C, also the date can only be changed in A. That is perfect.  However, could this be expanded to B and C ? So if you add a date to A, B or C then it isn't available to any of the others ? and you can only edit it in the date field it was added ? Thanks

@Tom I figured you might be looking to do that. It wasn't expressed in your post, but yes, you could add logic to cascade the selected dates into the following. Just need to break it down a bit more and be more targeted. For C, you would marge the Array from A and B and then set the dates. Give it a try and post again if you hit a wall.

Thanks I'll look at this today and post back with how I get on.

To start with I've tried adding an onSelect to mdp-demo-b but that doesn't seem to trigger. $("#mdp-demo-b").multiDatesPicker({   onSelect: function (dt, ui) {     console.log("B - Date Selected.")   } }) What have I done wrong ?

I've moved a bit further forward. If I select A, B or C and then pick a date, that date is disabled for the other date pickers. The issue is any further selections don't seem to work.  I've created a pen here:  https://codepen.io/Tom_T/pen/PoMyZWX  Thanks

@Tom this is where a State Diagram would help. When A has a Value or is changed, B and C should be updated to reflect the value of A as Disabled. When A & B have a value, C should be updated to reflect the values of A & B as Disabled. Is this the logic you're going for? What should happen if A & B have values and A is changed? Would B be reset?

If A has a value that should be blocked B & C. If B has a value that should be blocked for A & C and if C has a value that should be blocked for A & B. If you change a value in A, B or C then the other fields should reflect that change. The idea is there are 3 date pickers, but you can't pick the same dates in each of them. The dates can only be selected once across all fields. If a date is cleared then it becomes available to all fields. Thanks

do you have any further advice or examples for this. I've spent a lot of time today trying to get this working, but so far I'm not getting any nearer. Thanks

@Tom a little, got this so far but it is not finished: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/om7hu4ga/83/

When I try running this it returns an error. "<a class='gotoLine' href='#63:8'>63:8</a> Uncaught TypeError: dArr.each is not a function"

I've spent a long time trying to get this working and not getting any further. I'd be grateful if anyone has any ideas.

I've got this working. Please see my answer.

I've got this working using multiDatesPicker and created a fiddle here showing it working. https://jsfiddle.net/hb709gkx/
var array = []

$('input').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    multidate: true,
    beforeShow: function( a ) {
        $.each ( $('#' + a.id ).multiDatesPicker('getDates'), function( i, z )  {
            array.splice( $.inArray( z.trim() ,array ) ,1 );
        })
    },
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date );
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    },

    onClose: function(u, i) {
        array = []
        $.each ( $('.mdp' ), function( i, elm )  {
            if ( $('#' + elm.id ).val().length >= 1 )  {
                vals = $('#' + elm.id ).val().split( ',' )
                if ( vals.length >= 1 )  {
                    $.each ( vals , function ( p, q ) {
                        array.push( q.trim() )
                    })
                }
            }
        })
    }
});

This allows you to select dates in any of the date fields, they are then not available in the other date fields.  When you go into a field its dates can be deselected. Seems to work OK.
